# passing react element into storybook prop

Tags: javascript, next.js, storybook

I have the code below in `Page.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Header } from './Header';
import './page.css';

export const Page = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

  return (
    <article>
      <Header
        user={user}
        onLogin={() => setUser({ name: 'Jane Doe' })}
        onLogout={() => setUser(undefined)}
        onCreateAccount={() => setUser({ name: 'Jane Doe' })}
      />

      <section>
        { children }
      </section>
    </article>
  );
};
Page.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element
}
Page.defaultProps = {
  children: <h1>foo</h1>
}
```

The below jsx does indeed work properly:

```
<Page>
   <h1>bar</h1>
</Page>
```

However, attempting to modify the `children` parameter through Storybook's UI throws this error:
[image]
^before

---

[image]
^after

---

I believe this is because Storybook parses the input as a JSON. Is it possible to get it to parse the input as a React Element instead?